# Using memcache.add() instead of set()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

Usually I do:

```
if not memcache.get('mykey'):
   memcache.set('mykey', item)
```

However, today I saw `memcache.add()`, which appears to add an item only if it doesn't already exist. So is this equivalent to the code I have above? Can I just replace the code above with `memcache.add()`?

Also, and more importantly, I'm using AppStats, and under RPC Call Traces, I get to see if my request calls `memcache.set()` or `get()` or `datastore.put()` or `get()`. When using the 2 lines of code above, I don't see anything for `memcache.set()`, which is expected. However, using only `memcache.add()` (without checking if the item already exists) always calls `memcache.set()`, even though `memcache.add()` returned false (meaning a new item was not inserted). Why is this the case?

Comment: You should have a look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py#761) :)

Comment: @PaoloMoretti thanks for the link..what exactly am I looking for..

Comment: This question (or one similar) has already been asked on stackoverflow before, I would like to direct you too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678339/memcached-which-is-faster-doing-an-add-and-checking-result-or-doing-a-get - http://serverfault.com/questions/291681/add-vs-set-in-memcached

Comment: Thanks. My main question is the second part of the question though. It doesn't make sense that using add() still shows a RPC call for set(). That's what I'm mostly confused about..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code has a race condition: between checking for the presence of a value in memcache and inserting it, another process could have inserted a value, which you'll now overwrite. Using `memcache.add` does not suffer from this race condition.

I'm not sure what you mean by your second question; calling `memcache.add` should result only in an add call, never a set call. Can you include the code you're running in that case?

Comment: To be clear, if you just changed `set()` to `add()` there's still the possibility of a key collision, it's just that with `add()` you'll know about it via its return value?