# Memcached php add vs set performance

Tags: php, memcached

New to the php memcahed library in php. I was just wondering what the major difference between Memcached::add and Memcached::set are? Do both have the same performance over head and What is the advantage of using one over the other?

Another thing do these methods (::set and ::add) feature some sort of safe addition? Meaning, if the key doesnt exist in memcache it creates it, or if the key exist replace it? I do want to minimize duplicate keys. And the only way I can create some sort of safe adding is replacing first then checking if it was success, else create it.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is [documented on Memcached::add](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.add.php):

> **Memcached::add()** is similar to [Memcached::set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php), but the operation fails if the ***key*** already exists on the server.

`Memcached::add()` will return false if the key is already defined, meaning that's what you should use if you want to report an error for a duplicate key. Additionally, use [Memcached::getResultCode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.getresultcode.php) to check if the add was successful.

For performance comparisons, it may depend on the number of memcached servers, library versions and a number of factors specific to your application. Initially I would say it is a premature optimisation, but if you still want to compare, your best bet is to benchmark it with your own set-up.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered. Please use the sample code provided in the answer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678339/memcached-which-is-faster-doing-an-add-and-checking-result-or-doing-a-get). And the explanation in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/291681/add-vs-set-in-memcached) post. Also there is this new thing Larry Page invented that you can use. I think its called Google.